# MySQL Combining data from 2 tables into 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-insert

I currently have 2 tables:

```
CrawlData
id (autoincrement), Source, Destination, and some more columns

Nodes
id (autoincrement), URL
```

The **Nodes** table contains the distinct Source values from **CrawlData**

Now I would like to have a table that is a kind of look up table that contains the ID's from Nodes instead of the texts in Source and Destination from **CrawlData**

I can get all the ID's with a Select query using Join on the URL=Source and URL = Destination, but don't know how to combine these and then also to get them in a new table **Edges** with 2 columns:

- SourceNode (= id from Nodes where CrawlData.Source = URL)
- DestinationNode (= id from Nodes where CrawlData.Destination = URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `INSERT` the records returned by `SELECT` statement using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO Edges(SourceNode, DestinationNode)
SELECT  b.ID SourceNode,
        c.ID DestinationNode
FROM    CrawlData a
        INNER JOIN Nodes b
            ON a.Source = b.URL
        INNER JOIN Nodes c
            ON a.Destination = c.URL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

For faster execution, execute the following statements to add `INDEX` on the columns to avoid `FULL TABLE SCAN` which could be slow if doing on large RDBMS.

```
ALTER TABLE Nodes ADD INDEX (URL);
```

if happens that all values of `Source` and `Destination` column are present on `Nodes.URL`, declare these columns as foreign keys,

```
ALTER TABLE CrawlData 
      ADD CONSTRAINT cd_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (Source) REFERENCES Nodes(URL)
ALTER TABLE CrawlData 
      ADD CONSTRAINT cd_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (Destination) REFERENCES Nodes(URL)
```

otherwise, add normal index on them

```
ALTER TABLE CrawlData ADD INDEX (Source);
ALTER TABLE CrawlData ADD INDEX (Destination);
```

Comment: thx.. this seems to work, although it sure is a slow query. Has been running for over 30 minutes now and still busy.....

Comment: it's because the query is performing full table scan. have you tried to add the suggested indexes?

Comment: I cancelled the query and trying again now after following your tips on adding the indexes.. still taking long though. 

I'm wondering... wouldn't the 2 joins not be the same as "WHERE a.Source=b.URL and a.destination = c.URL" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can join twice to the Nodes table. Once, use the Source to join to URLK. The next time use the Destination.

Conceptually, it is like using two copies of the Nodes table, each with a different name (say "S" and "D"). You get:

```
select S.ID As SOURCE_ID, D.ID As DEST_ID
from CrawlData
join Nodes S on Source = S.URL
join Nodes D on Destination = D.URL
```